# In diagrams.net (ex draw.io), can I hide shapes having only one specific tag?

Tags: draw.io

While it is possible to [hide shapes having a specific tag among others](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000080137-work-with-custom-links), I was not yet able to only hide shapes having solely one specific tag.

E.g., this custom link also hides shapes having tags "tag1 tag2 tag3":

```
data:action/json,{"actions":[{"hide": {"tags": "tag1"}}]}
```

But I actually want to hide shapes having the tag "tag1" only.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood you well so this is my suggestion. I tested this with 2 shapes having "blue" tag and two shapes having "red" tag.
Then I added action link URL to hide e.g shapes with red tag (I suggest to use toggle so you could show/hide shapes)

data:action/json,{"actions":[{"toggle": {"tags": ["red"]}}]}

Does this help?
Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm afraid this doesn't solve my problem. Let's imagine that I would now add another tag "red" to your blue circle. Then the blue circle would have the tags "red" and "blue". When I then trigger your action above, then the red shapes would be hidden (as before) but also the circle - and I don't want the circle to hide, I want only the shapes to hide which have solely the tag "red" - so only this tag alone. Put another way, I want an action which only hides shapes having the "red" tag ONLY and no further tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here are screenshots. Hopefully this will be what you are looking for.

[image]

[image]